# delete characters after first numeral /number in string in R

Tags: r

I'm going through and cleaning a dataset that has location entries like : "Sarasota  Florida6h" I'm not sure why but all the strings have either 3 or 2 characters at the end starting with a number:

```
[413] "Los Angeles11h"                                      "Pittsburgh  PA1h"                                   
[415] "London  UK18h"                                       "Mumbai  India19h"                                   
[417] "Orange County CA1h"                                  "Columbus  OH2d"                                     
[419] "4d"                                                  "Sarasota  Florida6h"                                
[421] "Toronto9m"                                           "Adelaide Australia7h"                               
[423] "Wayland  MA4h"                                       "Scottsdale AZ USA1h"                                
[425] "Sydney  Australia6d"                                 "Connecticut  USA31m"                                
[427] "United States5m"                                     "Boulder  Colorado12h"                               
[429] "Berlin  Germany7h"                                   " India   Chaibasa1h"
```

I need a script to remove all letters after a numeral to clean these out:
I've tried the below, but clearly, there's something wrong here.

```
follow_dat$loc <- sapply(strsplit(follow_dat$Location, "\\[0-9]"), `[[`, 2)
```

Your kind assistance is appreciated.
Mari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions
for example you can clean them this way:

```
gsub("[0-9]..*","",follow_dat$Location)
```

What this expression is saying is "clean everything after you find a number with nothing '' in all follow_dat$Location"

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other numbers in your strings (as your example suggests), then we can use `gsub`,

```
gsub('[0-9]+[a-z]', '',follow_dat$Location)
```

Comment: Following me into every question :p

Comment: Thanks, tried this also. Both work great. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi, I tried but don't have enough point. Will come back when I do!